# Can I install 32 bit Ubuntu on dual boot with 64 bit windows 7?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dual-boot, 32-bit

I'm asking this because I've downloaded the Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit ISO, burned it to a CD and tried to install it on my PC but the installation screen never shows up. When I start the CD I choose "install ubuntu" and some codes run on my screen, then the screen becomes purple and says "ubuntu" and starts loading. Several minutes after, the screen goes black and it stays black for like forever.
Have I done something wrong? I don't know why I have this problem. I had Windows 7 64 bit on dual boot (wubi) with Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and it worked fine...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will not matter if you are installing the 32bit or the 64bit version.

As long as your computer supports 64bit instructions you can install any OS, 32 or 64bit as long as these play well with dual boot configurations.

I recommend you do a `md5sum` check on the image you downloaded and on the burned CD to make sure there are no faults in it, or if that is an option try to create a USB pen using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and test it that way.

If you system worked with the Wubi install there is no reason why the LiveCD would not work, maybe its just failing to load due to BIOS configuration or bad media.